# Convert canvas coordinates to screen position

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a point, which has map (canvas) coordinates and it would be great to have his screen position. I need this for setting cursor position in the same place, where point is located.

Do you know any way to convert this coordinates?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think something like the following could work in which you need to transform your map coordinates into screen coordinates using [QgsMapTool::toCanvasCoordinates](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapTool.html#aafeabd37aff50504a5480b3be805521e). Select a point in your layer then run the following in the **Python Console**:

```
from qgis.gui import QgsMapTool
from PyQt4.QtGui import QCursor

layer = iface.activeLayer()
for f in layer.selectedFeatures():
    geom = f.geometry()
    point = QgsMapTool(iface.mapCanvas()).toCanvasCoordinates(geom.asPoint())
    transformed_point = iface.mapCanvas().mapToGlobal(point)
    QCursor().setPos(transformed_point.x(), transformed_point.y())
```