# Getting screen coordinates from canvas coordinate using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt

I'm trying to set the initial position of my QGIS plugin dialog. I'm using .setGeometry() but the problem is that I don't know how to get coordinates. I want to set the initial position in the top corner of the canvas in QGIS (like the image below). I've tried this but it does not work.

```
self.dlg = SetZoomDialog()
canvasCenter = iface.mapCanvas().extent().center()
canvasToGlobal = iface.mapCanvas().mapToGlobal(QPoint(int(canvasCenter.x())/2, int(canvasCenter.y())/2))
x= canvasToGlobal.x()
y= canvasToGlobal.y()
self.dlg.setGeometry(x,y,width,height)
```

I tried also this `canvasToGlobal = QgsMapTool(iface.mapCanvas()).toCanvasCoordinates(canvasCenter)` but still I don't understand how to convert canvas coordinates to screen coordinates.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicated https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231422/convert-canvas-coordinates-to-screen-position

Comment: I've seen that, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not very difficult to do that. That position in Map Canvas corresponds to QPoint(0,0), so you only need 'mapToGlobal' **QgsMapCanvas** method to find screen coordinates. I used a test plugin for testing my approach. It can be observed in following code snippet.

```
.
.
.
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication, QVariant, QPoint
.
.
.

    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""
        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        mapcanvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
        point = mapcanvas.mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,0))
        self.dlg.move(point.x(), point.y())
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:
            # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
            # substitute with your code.
            pass
```

When I launch my plugin by clicking in corresponding icon, it appears in desired position; as it can be observed in following image:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I've asked for.

Comment: I’m happy to help.